# Spark : dataframe.repartition(num) remove first row from dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading a `dataframe` from `csv` file using `java` API and `Spark` CSV Reader .

`dataframe.show()` -> It shows all the rows from the csv 
but if I do `dataframe.repartition(1)` -> It removes the very first row from dataframe, How to debug the issue ??

I am using `SqlContext` of `spark` .

Comment: Can you please share your code snippet ? Because `dataframe.repartition(num)` never removes first row from dataframe.

Comment: I was using CustomRDD and getPartition always returns the same partition .